# AWS QuickSight rails integration authorization code error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

I have a rails application that needs to add QuickSight. Found that for these purposes it is necessary to use the `get_dashboard_embed_url` method. This method returns me the URL, but following it (manually, through an iframe tag) I get this error text

**Embedding failed because of invalid URL or authorization code. Both of these must be valid and the authorization code must not be expired for embedding to work.**

Where can I find the authenticate code? How can I get it? Thanks for your help

This is how i fetch the url

```
credential_options = {
  client: Aws::STS::Client.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION']),
  role_arn: ENV['QUICK_SIGHT_ROLE_ARN'],
  role_session_name: self.user_email
}

assume_role_credential = Aws::AssumeRoleCredentials.new(credential_options)
qs_client = Aws::QuickSight::Client.new({
  credentials: assume_role_credential,
  region: ENV['AWS_REGION']
})

begin
  qs_client.register_user({
    identity_type: 'IAM', # accepts IAM, QUICKSIGHT
    email: self.user_email,
    user_role: 'READER', # accepts ADMIN, AUTHOR, READER, RESTRICTED_AUTHOR, RESTRICTED_READER
    iam_arn: ENV['QUICK_SIGHT_ROLE_ARN'],
    session_name: self.user,
    aws_account_id: ENV['AWS_ACCOUNT_ID'],
    namespace: 'default'
  })
rescue
end

options = {
  aws_account_id: ENV['AWS_ACCOUNT_ID'],
  dashboard_id: ENV['QUICK_SIGHT_DASHBOARD_ID'],
  identity_type: 'IAM',
  session_lifetime_in_minutes: 300,
  undo_redo_disabled: false,
  reset_disabled: false
}

qs_client.get_dashboard_embed_url(options, {}).embed_url
```

And how i try to display 
`iframe src=@url class='w-100 h-100' style='min-height: 500px;'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first, sorry for my weak english, but i hope that you'll understand what i mean

Ok, after completing these points, everything began to work for me. Also read "Underwater rocks", this is very important points list which will save you tons of time

- Replace my code in question with this

  ```
  def fetch_url # this method fetch embed dashboard url
     credential_options = {
       client: Aws::STS::Client.new(
         region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
         access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
         secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
       ),
       role_arn: ENV['QUICK_SIGHT_ROLE_ARN'],
       role_session_name: self.user_email # This is attr_accessor :user_email
     }

     assume_role_credential = Aws::AssumeRoleCredentials.new(credential_options)
     qs_client = Aws::QuickSight::Client.new({
       credentials: assume_role_credential,
       region: ENV['AWS_REGION']
     })

     begin
       qs_client.register_user({
         identity_type: 'IAM', # accepts IAM, QUICKSIGHT
         email: self.user_email,
         user_role: 'READER', # accepts ADMIN, AUTHOR, READER, RESTRICTED_AUTHOR, RESTRICTED_READER
         iam_arn: ENV['QUICK_SIGHT_ROLE_ARN'],
         session_name: self.user_email,
         aws_account_id: 'ENV['AWS_ACCOUNT_ID']',
         namespace: 'default'
       })
     rescue
     end

     options = {
       aws_account_id: ENV['AWS_ACCOUNT_ID'],
       dashboard_id: ENV['QUICK_SIGHT_DASHBOARD_ID'],
       identity_type: 'IAM',
       session_lifetime_in_minutes: 300,
       undo_redo_disabled: false,
       reset_disabled: false
     }

     qs_client.get_dashboard_embed_url(options).embed_url
   end
  ```
- Go to **Manage QuickSight panel** `https://your-quicksight-region(us-east-2 for example).quicksight.aws.amazon.com/sn/admin#users` and click on "Manage permissions" button (button is placed above of the table with users)
- On the new page click on "Create" button and select "Sharing dashboards" checkbox. Set the name of the permission, click on the "Create" button
- In your controller action: `@url = fetch_url # fetch_url - method from 1 point`
- Add to your view: `iframe src=@url` **OR** you can use a [amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk) but for me the iframe works pretty well

***Underwater rocks***

- Remember that dashboard url (which you are get with this method `qs_client.get_dashboard_embed_url(options).embed_url`) can be used only once, i.e. you can't open two browsers tabs with the same URL. When you are will pass this URL to `iframe`, this URL will cease to be working and you will no longer be able to use it in others browser windows or others `iframe`'s
- Add your app domain to whitelist domains on the QuickSight. You can do it in the Manage QuickSight panel `https://your-quicksight-region.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/sn/admin#embedding`
- **!!!IMPORTANT!!!** if you are trying to embed dashboard to your `localhost:your_server_port_number` rails server, then you will always get the error message into the `iframe` (but if you go to this URL through the address bar of the browser, then you should see your dashboard (comment out / remove the `iframe` so it doesn't use the link, because every *embedded dashboard url* is disposable)). This is because `localhost:your_server_port_number` is not provided in the whitelist (Underwater rocks p.2). For resolving this issue and testing your work you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) (maybe it's available only for macOS, i'm not sure).

  When you'll download the `ngrok` open your terminal and run command

  `$ ./path_to_ngrok_script/./ngrok http your_server_port_number`

  For me it's:

  `$ ~/./scripts/ngrok http 3000`


  After that do these 3 things for adding your work station to QuickSight whitelist:
- In the terminal with `ngrok` copy generated domain which starts with
  the `https` (i'll name it ngrok_domain), **NOT WITH HTTP**. For
  example: https://047956358355.ngrok.io
- Go to the Underwater rocks p.2 and add ngrok_domain
- Open your browser and go to the path with `iframe`, but use ngrok_domain instead of localhost:3000. For example, your embedded dashboard path is `localhost:3000/embed_dashboard`. Change it to `https://047956358355.ngrok.io/embed_dashboard`

After all these steps all is start working for me. I'm sure that some of the points here are superfluous, but i'm really tired of working with this integration, so here you yourself decide what should be left and what should be removed.

I hope my answer helped at least someone

Comment: It worked great with ngRok

Comment: How can we load the same dashboard in mobile apps?